Blazor - Validate datalist from child component
I have written a Blazor testapp that has an EditForm with a child component in the parent component.
The child component consists of an input with type search for a datalist.
A method returns a result from the list with @oninput. The selection is returned to the parent via EventCallback using @focusout Event and can be saved in an object with the other inputs in the parent EditForm using Submit.
As soon as the validation is active, I would check the return value of the child component and set Validation = true with string.NotEmptyOrWhitespace(value) == false.
Can someone please tell me how I can implement this or another option to validate the data in child component?
Enclosed is my demo code:
Parent component
@page "/newentry"

<h3>New Entry</h3>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="raw">
        <div class="col-2">
            <EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleOnSubmit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <label>
                    Value:
                <InputNumber @bind-Value="inputRecipe.Value"/>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inputRecipe.Value)" />
                </label>
                <ComboBoxComponent OnCategorySelected="HandleCategorySelected"></ComboBoxComponent>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inputRecipe.Category)" />
                <label>Comment:
                <InputTextArea @bind-Value="inputRecipe.Comment"/>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inputRecipe.Comment)" />
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Save</button>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    EditContext? editContext;

    private string returnCatValue = "";
    DisplayRecipeModel inputRecipe = new();

    private void HandleOnSubmit()
    {
        List<DisplayRecipeModel> test = new();
        inputRecipe.Category = returnCatValue;
        test.Add(inputRecipe);
    }

    private void HandleCategorySelected(string selectedCategory)
    {       
        returnCatValue = selectedCategory;
    }
}

Child Component
@using BlazorApp.Models

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div>
            <label>Category:</label>
        </div>
        <input type="search" list="categorylist" @bind-value="searchTermCat" @oninput="GetCatResult" @onfocusout="HandleReturnCatValue"/>
        <datalist id="categorylist">
            @foreach (var item in recipes!)
            {
                <option value="@item.Category" />
            }
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    private string? searchTermCat = "";
    private List<DisplayRecipeModel> catResult = new();

    [Parameter]
    public DisplayRecipeModel? recipe { get; set; }

    List<DisplayRecipeModel>? recipes = new()
    {
        new DisplayRecipeModel
        {
            Category = "Fun",
            Payment = "Cash"
        },
        new DisplayRecipeModel
        {
            Category = "Cloth",
            Payment = "Card"
        },
        new DisplayRecipeModel
        {
            Category = "Food",
            Payment = "Mastercard"
        }
    };

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnCategorySelected { get; set; }

    private void GetCatResult()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTermCat) == false)
        {
            recipes = catResult.Where(sq => sq.Category!.Contains(searchTermCat)).ToList();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private void HandleReturnCatValue()
    {
        OnCategorySelected.InvokeAsync(searchTermCat);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

**
Class Model**
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlazorApp.Models;

public class DisplayRecipeModel
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Category { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "comment to long")]
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}

I would appreciate any help
thanks in advance

Problem solved.
The return value from child component must be added to the Object in HandleCategorySelected Event.
private void HandleCategorySelected(string selectedCategory)
{
returnCatValue = selectedCategory;
inputRecipe.Category = returnCatValue;
}
